# Replace exact content or tag

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I think that to replace exactly one tag, the best is to use `preg_replace`. I tried `str_replace` and replaced all characters. For example if I want replace the two PHP tags in `<?php print "Hello parents";  ?>` by using `str_replace` I do this :

```
$char1=array("<?php","?>");
$char_2=array("","");

str_replace($char1,$char2,$content);
```

The result will be this :

```
Hello parents
```

**`str_replace` "replace all chars"**

How can I do the same thing with `preg_replace`? Because I don't understand how to put chars or separators

Here is what I tried :

```
$content="<?php Hello parents?>"
$chars='/(\<?php),(?>)/i';
$sus="";
echo preg_replace($chars, $sus, $content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content="<?php Hello parents?>"
$chars = "/(<\?php|\?>)/i";
$sus="";
echo preg_replace($chars, $sus, $content);
```

You can use the `|` separator to say replace `<?php` or `?>`
And the `?` character needs to be escaped as within the RegEx it means 0 or 1 occurances